# How to keep Java FXML active while file is loading

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, fxml

I am using JAVA FXML GUI to parse a text file. The user can select which file to parse and then press "load". When the user clicks on "load" the file gets parse and many lines gets added to an ArrayList. The user then search and manipulate the text that was parse that is store in the ArrayList.

Sometimes while loading/writing the file to the ArrayList or manipulating some lines, the GUI is not responsive. How can I separate the GUI process vs. the ArrayList handling in order for the GUI to always be accessible to the user ?

The code below launches my application:

```
package javafxapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Javafxapp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    FXMLDocumentController controller = new FXMLDocumentController();
    controller.openingSound();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: "How to do one thing while another is happening?" Sounds like a case for multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a textbook case for the use of multithreading.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) JavaFX documentation for information and tutorials on how to begin using it.